# a person with a fossilized mind

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

How to describe a person who have a fossilized mind?

whatever he hears he will not (get it into one's head)

Comment: By fossilized do you mean to indicate that the individual is too stupid to understand new concepts, or too stubborn to change his perspective?  The answers will vary depending on your answer.

Comment: I agree with @Lumberjack, your definition of a fossilized mind seems to suggest that the person does not understand. Get into one's head is used when a concept/notion/idea etc. is not able to be assimilated.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I should write inflexible instead of fossilized, I meant a person who's too stubborn to change his perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Close-minded](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/close-minded)**

> not willing to try new things or consider other opinions

Also spelled as *[closed-minded](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/close-minded)*

Also consider **[ossified](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ossified)**

> having become set and inflexible

Alternatives are

> - stubborn
> - bull-headed
> - pig-headed
> - narrow-minded
> - hard-headed

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I typically equate "closed-minded" to one who is [obstinate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obstinate) or [stubborn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stubborn), as opposed to one who is too stupid to learn new concepts.

Comment: @Lumberjack I like obstinate. Offer it.

Comment: Thanks @bib I may very well do that.  I have added a comment requesting clarification from OP.  My answer will vary depending on which way he goes with it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of "thickheaded":

> thickheaded — (of a person) dull-witted; stupid

The connotation is one of stupidity or inability to understand something:

> Alice is so thickheaded she couldn't understand the instructions you sent to her.
>
> Bob is pretty thickheaded so you may need to use small words.